# Generate library with makefile : No rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile

```
CC= gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -g
INCLUDES= -I/usr/local/include/
LFLAGS= -L/usr/local/lib64
LDFLAGS=
LIBS= -L. -lrabbitmq
SRCS= amqp_connection.c amqp_consumer.c amqp_deconnection.c amqp_producer.c amqp_utils.c
OBJS= $(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXEC=amqp_test

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est généré"

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~ *.o $(EXEC)
```

> #### I want to generate a library not an executable
>
> Can you help me please ?
> I launched "make" and the result is :

> make: *** No rule to make target
> `amqp_connection.o', needed by` amqp_test'.  Stop. amqp_test is the
> name of the file which contain the main().

The sources are :

> amqp_connection / amqp_consumer /amqp_deconnection / amqp_producer
> [image]

Comment: For a static library, you use `ar` to create the library from the list of object files: `$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIBNAME.a) $(OBJS)` (given `LIBNAME.a = libxyz.a`, for example). For a shared library, you typically use the C compiler with a special option (`-shared` for `gcc`) to collect the object files into a shared object: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $(LIBNAME.so) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)` (given `LIBNAME.so = libxyz.so`) for example, where the load flags and libraries specify any dependencies that the shared object will need at run-time.

Comment: Your makefile says the source files have names ending in `.c`, contrary to what your question text claims.  From the error message, it appears that you do not have the file `amqp_connection.c` (or any other source file with the base name `amqp_connection` and an extension that `make` recognizes) available to be compiled into the corresponding `.o` file.  If your comment about the files being `ampq_connection` etc without the `.c` suffix is accurate, then you need to rename the source files so that they have the correct extension.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: can you send me a solution please. because, it's my first exercice with makefile

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the sources have the correct extension .c

Comment: I can't send a solution — I don't know what type of library you're trying to create, nor do I know why `make` can't find the file `amqp_connection.c` which you say exists and it says does not exist.

Comment: You should update your question to better reflect the reality of the file names.

Comment: Are the source files in the current working directory?  i.e. the directory from which you invoke `make`?

Comment: To expand on @JonathanLeffler, typically make has [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html)  to generate .o files from .c files.   The fact that it says it has no rule to build the .o file means it either has those rules disabled (using the `-r` flag when calling make), or it can't find the .c file to generate the .o file from it.   Check that the file exists and is in the directory that the Makefile is in.

Comment: @G.M. , yes the makfile is in the same directory with the sources

Comment: @HardcoreHenry : i was added a picture, that contain the content of the folder

Comment: According to your latest edit the source files are *not* in the same directory as the `makefile` -- `Makefile` is in the current working directory but the source files are in a subdirectory named `src`.

Comment: @G.M., so we should change the makefile in the src folder ?

Comment: or add the prefix `src/` to all of your sources...  (which is better practice).   I'll post an example.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry : thanks, my goal to build a static library, which flags we should use ?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry : yes it's useful when i add sr/ , thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example file using some common practices.   Here, I'm redefining the source directory and the object directory, and defining an implicit rule to build the objects given a source in a different directory.

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := obj
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/
LFLAGS := -L/usr/local/lib64
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS := -L. -lrabbitmq
SRCS_RAW := amqp_connection.c amqp_consumer.c amqp_deconnection.c amqp_producer.c amqp_utils.c

SRCS := $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW))
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW:.c=.o))
EXEC := amqp_test

$(info DEBUG: SRCS=$(SRCS))
$(info DEBUG: OBJS=$(OBJS))
$(info DEBUG: EXEC=$(EXEC))

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est généré"

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

#rule to create object directory if it doesnt exist
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

#define implicit rule to build objects in their own directory
#(note -- order only dependency on object directory)
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~  $(EXEC)
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)
```

Comment: I have an error when i launched "make"-->                                                                 
Makefile:12: *** unterminated call to function `addprefix': missing `)'.  Stop.

Comment: sorry, missed a closing brace.  Updated target.

Comment: An other error " missing separator"----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG: SRCS=src/amqp_connection.c src/amqp_consumer.c src/amqp_deconnection.c src/amqp_producer.c src/amqp_utils.c
DEBUG: OBJS=obj/amqp_connection.o obj/amqp_consumer.o obj/amqp_deconnection.o obj/amqp_producer.o obj/amqp_utils.o
DEBUG: EXEC=amqp_test  
#Makefile:24: *** missing separator.  Stop.#

Comment: That's likely due to tabs instead of spaces.   Check that all your recipe lines begin with tabs

Comment: Actually, i have an other problem, it can't find header files -----------------------------
gcc -Wall -g  -c src/amqp_connexion.c -o obj/amqp_connexion.o
src/amqp_connexion.c:26:21: fatal error: libamqp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libamqp.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/amqp_connexion.o] Error 1

Comment: I added $(INCLUDES) in this line --> $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDES)